# Why do double curly braced children cause my React.memo component to re-render even though the values are the same?

Tags: reactjs

Memoization doesn't seem to work for me when the children of a component are specified.

```js
const Cell = React.memo(({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>{children}</div>
  );
});
```

In multiple curly brackets, the component re-renders every time.

```js
<Cell key={`o${outerIndex}i${innerIndex}`}>
  {`${outerIndex}`}
  {`${innerIndex}`}
</Cell>
```

as opposed to one curly bracket which renders only once as expected.

```js
<Cell key={`o${outerIndex}i${innerIndex}`}>
  {`${outerIndex}${innerIndex}`}
</Cell>
```

I've created a contrived [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rr6y1v1jxn) example to show this.

Lines `50, 51, 52` are the ones in question. See the comment above them.

Comment: Please put a [mcve] *in the question*.

Comment: I think it has to do with number of children, when you have only one (combined)  it works whereas for 2 children that change in different rates it breaks memoization.

Comment: also according to [react.memo docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) performance boost is **only in some cases** where react can tell the diff by shallow diffing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's log the `children` and see what happens:

```js
const Cell = React.memo(({ children }) => {
  console.log(children);
  return <div>{children}</div>;
});
```

1. For

```
{`${outerElem}${innerElem}`}
```

You get

```
00 
01 
10 
11
```

2. For

```
{`${outerElem}`}
{`${innerElem}`}
```

You get:

```js
["0", "0"]
["0", "1"]
["1", "0"]
["1", "1"]
```

As mentioned on [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) docs, shallowly comparing will result:

```
00 === 00                    // No render
["0", "0"] !== ["0", "0"]    // Re-Render
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/4xvyvxzzq4?fontsize=14)

---

To address the issue *"Provide a custom comparison function as the second argument"*.

```
React.memo(MyComponent, areEqual);
```

Comment: exactly what I was trying to say, a workaround is to use custom Equal comparator